# powershell query with graph api

Tags: powershell, microsoft-graph-api

i'm trying to execute with powershell follow query:

```
$upn = "example@example.com"
$URL = "https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users?$filter=mail eq '$upn'"

#Send Request
Invoke-RestMethod -Method GET -Uri $URL -Headers $headers
```

command run but does not return the user in the query but the list of first 100 users. On ms doc the url is that one. What is wrong?

The service principal that i'm using have user.readwrite.all permission

Comment: Try putting URL into a web browser and see if it returns the users.  We need to determine if the query need to be modified or just being able to scrap the results in the response.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simple issue, you have to escape the `$` dollar sign in your URL.

The code:

```
$upn = "example@example.com"
$URL = "https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users?$filter=mail eq '$upn'"
```

When you look at the contents of the `$URL` variable:

```
PS C:\> $URL
https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users?=mail eq 'example@example.com'
```

You will notice that the `$filter` is missing, and therefore the API will return all the users. PowerShell is interpreting the string and expanding the `$filter` variable for you... even if that variable is empty/doesn't exist and you didn't mean for it to be interpreted as a variable. You can simply add a back tick character (`` ` ``) before `$filter` to escape:

```
$upn = "example@example.com"
$URL = "https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users?`$filter=mail eq '$upn'"
```